# Strtotime outputs wrong date

Tags: php, timestamp

Given the following string: "03-02-2015" (d-m-Y format), when I apply

```
strtotime("03-02-2015");
```

it gives me 1422914400.

When I transform it back into date again, just to verify, using more unix timestamp convertors on the internet, they prompt: **02-02-2015**.

*Why does strtotime convert the string into a timestamp which is actually yesterday? How can I fix this?*

For `strtotime("now")` it outputs the correct results when verified with convertors on the internet.

Comment: You probably have a problem with Time zone

Comment: @HoboSapiens then why strtotime("now") otputs the correct result (verified with online convertors it gives me 03-02-3015)?

Comment: @HoboSapiens How can I fix this?

Comment: Just tell what output you want

Comment: @SunilPachlangia I want strtotime to generate the correct timestamp (the one corresponding to today, not yesterday).

Comment: use date('d-m-Y',strtotime(1422914400));

Comment: var_dump(strtotime("03-02-2015"));
 var_dump(date('d-m-y',strtotime("03-02-2015"))); RESULT:  int(1422918000)

string(8) "03-02-15"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using more unix timestamp convertors on the internet

Forget them, your language PHP itself provides you ways to handle that, use them

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("03-02-2015"));
```

Prints

```
2015-02-03
```

There is nothing wrong with that strtotime output.

> @SunilPachlangia I want strtotime to generate the correct timestamp (the one corresponding to today, not yesterday)

Then simply use

```
$timestamp=time();
```

Now for the real reason why you see different dates. One single Unix timestamp will show different time on different time zones, since time zones vary quiet a bit you can see one day difference if the place where you generated the timestamp uses a different time zone compared to where you are using that timestamp.

Here is a practical demonstration for you

```
<?php
$ts=strtotime("03-02-2015");                        //2015-02-03
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
echo date("Y-m-d",$ts);                             //2015-02-02 :)
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/PE4Xlwet)**